# Module operator overridign

Tags: c#, module, operators, complex-numbers

I have a `struct` for Complex Numbers. I want to be able to run something like:

```
Complex a = new Complex( 3, 5 );
Console.WriteLine("|a| = {0}", |a|);
```

Is `|a|` possible to create? If it is, how to?

Comment: You can't do that. `|` will always be a two-operand operator.

Answer (score 3):

[Overloadable Operators (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) lists the following overloadable operators:

> C# allows user-defined types to overload operators by defining static member functions using the operator keyword. Not all operators can be overloaded, however, and others have restrictions, as listed in this table:
>
> +, -, !, ~, ++, --, true, false
>   These unary operators can be overloaded.
>
> +, -, *, /, %, &, |, ^, <<, >>
>   These binary operators can be overloaded.
>
> ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=
>   The comparison operators can be overloaded (but see the note that follows this table).
>
> &&, ||
>   The conditional logical operators cannot be overloaded, but they are evaluated using & and |, which can be overloaded.
>
> []
>   The array indexing operator cannot be overloaded, but you can define indexers.
>
> (T)x
>   The cast operator cannot be overloaded, but you can define new conversion operators (see explicit and implicit).
>
> +=, -=, *=, /=, %=, &=, |=, ^=, <<=, >>=
>   Assignment operators cannot be overloaded, but +=, for example, is evaluated using +, which can be overloaded.
>
> =, ., ?:, ??, ->, =>, f(x), as, checked, unchecked, default, delegate, is, new, sizeof, typeof
>   These operators cannot be overloaded.

You cannot define new operators.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of, you can't use the |a| syntax like you've got above - but you can override the ToString() method for basic output, or create custom properties to generate the format you'd wish to output. For example, with this class definition:

```
public class Complex
{
    public int Real { get; protected set; }
    public int Imag { get; protected set; }

    public Complex(int a, int b)
    {
        Real = a; Imag = b;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} + {1}i", Real, Imag);
    }

    public string AbsoluteValue
    {
        get { return string.Format("sqrt({0}² + {1}²)", Real, Imag); }
    }
}
```

You can do stuff like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Complex c = new Complex(2, 6);
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    Console.WriteLine(c.AbsoluteValue);
}
```

To generate output like this:

```
2 + 6i
sqrt(2² + 6²)
```